# How do I transform this table in snowflake?

Tags: pivot, transpose, snowflake-schema

I'm having trouble here in a table in snowflake.

Imagine I have this table:

| Event_name | Event_Params_Key | Event_Params_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | page_url | [www.url.com](http://www.url.com) |
| XXX | campaign | campaign1 |
| XXX | id | 1 |

How can I transform this into:

| Event_name | id | page_url | campaign |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 1 | [www.url.com](http://www.url.com) | campaign1 |

I've tried use pivot function here, but I got nowhere -.- Can you help?

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT EVENT_NAME, EVENT_PARAMS_KEY, EVENT_PARAMS_VALUES
  FROM GA4_EVENTS
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(EVENT_PARAMS_VALUES)
  FOR EVENT_PARAMS_KEY IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT EVENT_PARAMS_KEY FROM GA4_EVENTS
  )
);
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot how does your example differ from the one in docs?

Comment: In case you want dynamically set column names, use this https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Create-a-dynamic-PIVOT-in-Snowflake